# Undefined output when using getPair and getReserves in web3 / node.js

Tags: web3js, uniswap, ethers.js, bsc, pancakeswap

Happy new year to you all!

I am trying to get the wBNB/BUSD pair address from Pancakeswap (using getPair) and then check for their liquidity (using getReserves). I have pretty much copied the code below as a working code from somewhere else. Nonetheless, getPair output is undefined. What am I missing here?

```
const Web3   = require('web3');
const web3   = new Web3("https://bsc-dataseed1.binance.org:443");
const routeraddress    = '0x10ed43c718714eb63d5aa57b78b54704e256024e' // PANCAKESWAP ROUTER
const bnbAddress       = '0xbb4CdB9CBd36B01bD1cBaEBF2De08d9173bc095c' // contract for WBNB
const busdAddress      = '0xe9e7cea3dedca5984780bafc599bd69add087d56'; // BUSD

const liqABI = [{"inputs":[],"name":"decimals","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"token0","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"factory","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"name":"getPair","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"getReserves","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint112","name":"_reserve0","type":"uint112"},{"internalType":"uint112","name":"_reserve1","type":"uint112"},{"internalType":"uint32","name":"_blockTimestampLast","type":"uint32"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"}];

var cakeFactory = new web3.eth.Contract(liqABI, routeraddress); // CONTACT PANCAKE ABI

cakeFactory.methods.getPair(bnbAddress, busdAddress).call(function (err,pairAddress) {
    console.log("Pair Address: ", pairAddress);

    var pair = new web3.eth.Contract(liqABI, pairAddress);
    pair.methods.getReserves().call(function( err,Reserves) {
    console.log("Pair Reserves: ", Reserves);
})
})
```

Answer (score 0):

dont use the router contract.

Change this:

```
const routeraddress    = '0x10ed43c718714eb63d5aa57b78b54704e256024e' // PANCAKESWAP ROUTER
```

For this:

```
const pancakeSwapFactoryAddress = '0xcA143Ce32Fe78f1f7019d7d551a6402fC5350c73'; // PancakeSwap V2 factory
```

The full code would be like

```
const Web3 = require('web3');
const web3   = new Web3("https://bsc-dataseed1.binance.org:443");
// const routeraddress    = '0x10ed43c718714eb63d5aa57b78b54704e256024e' // PANCAKESWAP ROUTER
const pancakeSwapFactoryAddress = '0xcA143Ce32Fe78f1f7019d7d551a6402fC5350c73'; // PancakeSwap V2 factory
const token0       = '0xbb4cdb9cbd36b01bd1cbaebf2de08d9173bc095c' // contract for WBNB
const token1      = '0xe9e7cea3dedca5984780bafc599bd69add087d56'; // BUSD

const liqABI = [{"inputs":[],"name":"decimals","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"token0","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"factory","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"name":"getPair","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"getReserves","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint112","name":"_reserve0","type":"uint112"},{"internalType":"uint112","name":"_reserve1","type":"uint112"},{"internalType":"uint32","name":"_blockTimestampLast","type":"uint32"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"}];

var cakeFactory = new web3.eth.Contract(liqABI,  pancakeSwapFactoryAddress); // CONTACT PANCAKE ABI

cakeFactory.methods.getPair(token0, token1).call(function (err,pairAddress) {
    console.log("Pair Address: ", pairAddress);

    if (pairAddress) {
        var pair = new web3.eth.Contract(liqABI, pairAddress);
        pair.methods.getReserves().call(function( err,Reserves) {
            console.log("Pair Reserves: ", Reserves);
        })
    }
})
```

Comment: Such a silly mistake! Thank you for pointing it out. I was running in circles because I am also new to Javascript. I appreciate your comment!